# Error in accessing php web service

Tags: php, android, web-services, http

I am having my webservice wrote in php hosted on byethost.com
It is working fine on browser and also on "http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/".
But when i make a call to service from android application it gives error.

> 05-06 00:31:34.475: E/AndroidRuntime(24246): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Host name may not be null
>   05-06 00:31:34.475: E/AndroidRuntime(24246):    at org.apache.http.HttpHost.(HttpHost.java:83)
>   05-06 00:31:34.475: E/AndroidRuntime(24246):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.determineTarget(AbstractHttpClient.java:519)
>   05-06 00:31:34.475: E/AndroidRuntime(24246):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:509)
>   05-06 00:31:34.475: E/AndroidRuntime(24246):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
>   05-06 00:31:34.475: E/AndroidRuntime(24246):    at com.shreeji.jsonparser.JSONParser.getJSONFromUrl(JSONParser.java:47)
>   05-06 00:31:34.475: E/AndroidRuntime(24246):    at apidatahandler.TilesApiCall.getTilesDetails(TilesApiCall.java:23)
>   05-06 00:31:34.475: E/AndroidRuntime(24246):    at com.shreejitiles.android.Ui_MainPage$1.run(Ui_MainPage.java:41)
>   05-06 00:31:34.475: E/AndroidRuntime(24246):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

Please help me.

code i am using to parse get response from server.

```
package com.shreeji.jsonparser;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.util.Log;

public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }

    public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url, List<NameValuePair> params)
            throws ClientProtocolException, IOException, JSONException {

        Log.i("url", url);

        // Making HTTP request

        // defaultHttpClient
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,
                "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();

        jObj = new JSONObject(json);

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its because you have not set host url for your request.

Comment: i set the url same as i am trying in to browser
http://www.example.byethost18.com/Api/getWalltiles.php?action=1
,but it works fine in browser and not in android application.

Comment: Did that also but dosent work same error msg.
I also tried requesting the url or hurl.it bur it wont work there.
it works fine in my browser though.

Comment: You are initializing httpPost wrongly.Its URI not URL. Try this-> 

`HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(new URI(url));`

Comment: Bro same code posted above works fine for my other apis hosted on other server

Comment: Can you try with `HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(new URI(url));` once?
And again if it is not solving the problem, can you check what is the value of `url` param?

Comment: checked bro 
i loged all the thing and params i passed action=1
and url is same as i mentioned to you .
It makes no difference bro

Comment: Are you passing action=1 in url?
If yess, then thats a wrong way, its an parameter, so need to set it as parameter for `httpPost` and url should be -> example.byethost18.com/Api/getWalltiles.php

Comment: i am not passing action=1 in url.
i am passing it as httppost entity.
look at my code carefully